# Create object with variable attributes in a cleaner way in python

Tags: python

Am new to python and I had to create an object only with certain attributes that are not `None`. Example:

```
if self.obj_one is None and self.obj_two is None:
    return MyObj(name=name)
elif self.obj_one is not None and self.obj_two is None:
    return MyObj(name=name, obj_one=self.obj_one)
elif self.obj_one is None and self.obj_two is not None:
    return MyObj(name=name, obj_two=self.obj_two)
else:
    return MyObj(name=name, obj_one=self.obj_one, obj_two=self.obj_two)
```

Coming from a Java land I know python is full of short hand so wanted to know if there is a cleaner way for writing the above? Of course my actual object has plenty more attributes. I tried searching but couldn't find anything helpful so am in doubt if its possible or not cause this doesn't scale if there are more than 2 variable attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way could be using the [double-star operator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument), like this:

```
kwargs = {'name': name}

if self.obj_one is not None:
    kwargs['obj_one'] = self.obj_one
if self.obj_two is not None:
    kwargs['obj_two'] = self.obj_two

return MyObj(**kwargs)
```

In plain words: you construct a dictionary with your keyword arguments, and then pass that dictionary preceded by `**` to the callable.

However, `None` is *often* (not always) used as a default value for optional arguments. *Probably* this will work too:

```
return MyObj(name=name, obj_one=self.obj_one, obj_two=self.obj_two)
```

without any `if` or that sort of stuff.